# Correctly displaying text from a file in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, filereader

I am currently trying to read multiple files (UTF-8) within a directory and store each element in that text file into an array.

I am able to get the text to print to console however it shows some funny characters I can't seem to rid myself off (See image - what is should look like is displayed on the right).

Currently, I have a method that builds an array with all file names in that directory then using a for loop I send each of these file names to a read method which puts it into a string.

**The below method writes these file names to an array.**

```
 public static ArrayList<String> readModelFilesInModelDir() {
    File folder = new File("Models/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String random = "";
    assert listOfFiles != null;
    ArrayList<String> listOfModelFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            //System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
            listOfModelFiles.add(listOfFiles[i].getName());
        } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
    System.out.println(listOfModelFiles);

    return listOfModelFiles;
```

**The below for loop then sends these file names to the read method.**

```
ArrayList<String> modelFiles = readModelFilesInModelDir();
    for (int i = 0; i < modelFiles.size(); i++) {
        String thisString = readModelFileIntoArray(modelFiles.get(i));
        System.out.println(thisString);
    }
```

**The below method then reads the string into an array, which is outputting what the images show.**

```
 public static String readModelFileIntoArray(String modelFilePath) {
    StringBuilder fileHasBeenRead = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(("Models/" + modelFilePath)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String s;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while ((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileHasBeenRead.append(s + "\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    return fileHasBeenRead.toString().trim();
}
```

Finally, how would I fix this output issue as well as store each of these files that have been read into a seperate array that I can use elsewhere? Thanks!

[image: What is does look like][image: What is should look like]

Comment: Does changing the encoding to UTF-16 help?

Comment: " how would I ... store each of these files that have been read into a seperate array that I can use elsewhere?" - I'd start by returning an actual array from `readModelFileIntoArray()` (or better a `List<String>`) than just a `String`. However, since your files seem to just contain key value pairs, using a `Map<String, Double>` or `Map<String, BigDecimal>` might make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Johnny Mopp, your file is encoded in UTF-16, not in UTF-8. The two `��` at the beginning of your output looks like a [byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). In UTF-16, each character is coded on two bytes. Since your text only contains characters in the ASCII range, it means that each first byte is always 0x00. This is why you're seeing all these `▯`: they correspond to the non-printable character 0x00. I would even say that since the two characters following `��` are `▯` and `a` in this order, your file is using big-endian UTF-16.

Instead of UTF-8, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_16`. It will also take the BOM into account and use the appropriate endianness.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier (and usually better) to use existing libraries for common stuff. There is `FileUtils` from apache commons-io, that provides this functionality out of the box, reducing your file reading code to a one liner

```
String thisString = FileUtils.readFileToString("Models/" + modelFilePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

... or whatever charset your file is using...

Comment: [1] It's usually better to use libraries, but Apache's  `FileUtils.readFileToString()` is not the right tool for this job since you would still have to parse the returned string. [2] The JDK already provides similar (better) functionality with [Files.readAllLines()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-), returning the file content in a `List<String>`. That method seems more appropriate for the OP's needs, and doesn't require third-party code. [3] Your answer doesn't really address the question.